# CarPlay starts playing music after activating Siri even if no music was playing before

Tags: music, siri, podcasts, car-integration

This issue has been driving me nuts: if I listen to music or a podcast, pause it, and then activate Siri using “Hey Siri,” the moment the Siri interaction ends it resumes playing the music/podcast, even though it has been paused before. This is natural behavior for when I interrupt playing audio, but very annoying when I’m driving with no music on.

I’ve tested this and it happens with Spotify and the Apple Podcasts app, suggesting it’s a system-level issue. It doesn’t happen if there’s nothing playing in the “now playing” drop down in control center. It also doesn’t happen is I force quit the audio app before activating Siri.

Is there some setting I can tweak to change this behavior, or is this just a bug?

Comment: Question: When you are pausing the audio you are playing, are you hitting the pause button on the screen or hitting a physical button on the console of the vehicle?

Comment: Good question. I don't have a touchscreen, but rather a knob that cycles through the carplay screens. I use both that knob to bring up and press the "pause" button on the relevant all, and the dedicated button on the steering wheel that pauses the music. Next time I'm in the car I'll check whether the two yield the same behavior.

Comment: I have found that the play/pause button on the screen will actually stop the music. The volume button can also act as a play/pause button, but when I call up Siri, the music will play once she is done. I wasn't sure if there was a bug or some strange design, but I learned a muscle memory to hit the correct button.

Comment: This is the correct answer: I tried this and it looks like clicking the button causes the volume to go to zero, which apparently automatically pauses playback. Feel free to add this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the play/pause button on the screen will actually stop the music. The volume button can also act as a play/pause button, but when I call up Siri, the music will play once she is done. I wasn't sure if there was a bug or some strange design, but I learned a muscle memory to hit the correct button.