# How to hear just Maps' spoken directions, without triggering music/podcasts?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, podcasts, maps, navigation

I have my iPhone 13 Pro connected via Bluetooth to my car stereo.  Normally, I listen to podcasts or music while navigating via Maps.  The spoken directions momentarily pause the music or podcast.  Sometimes glitchy, but mostly seems to work as designed/expected.

The other day I was with a passenger and just wanted spoken directions.  I was having a conversation and did not want to hear the podcast.  **I just wanted spoken directions and silence.**  Except for Apple Maps spoken directions, I do not want anything else playing during my trip.

This simple thing seems to be impossible to do.  After each spoken direction, my podcast resumes, forcing me to manually hit the stop button on the car stereo.

Force-quitting the Podcast app made no difference.  After the next spoken direction, my last podcast just resumes playing.

What is going on here?  Why is it impossible to just hear spoken directions and nothing else??

My issue is very similar to this, but "solution" here does not seem to work:

[CarPlay starts playing music after activating Siri even if no music was playing before](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/423172/6943)

---

Like the answer below and other online sources, it's suggested to disable cellular data for the Music and Podcast apps.  I tried that.  It makes no difference.  The Podcast is already saved on my phone and it just resumes playing.  So far, no viable workarounds or solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Found this link: [How to Stop iPhone From Auto-Playing Music In Car](https://www.techbout.com/stop-iphone-auto-playing-music-in-car-58965/), that possibly contains a correct solution. Specifically, the 1st solution that says:

**Disable Autoplay in Car’s Infotainment System**

*For this you need to access the settings of your Car’s infotainment system and see if there is an option to disable or Turn OFF Auto-Play.*

However, if this first solution does not work for you, I believe the best possible solution will be to disable the use of Cellular Data within the Apple Music app and the Podcasts app (depending on which apps you use for podcasts/music). This will prevent the music from playing but still allow you to use Apple Maps. [Here is a guide on how to disable Cellular Data for the Apple Music app (scroll to solution #6)](https://www.igeeksblog.com/how-to-stop-iphone-from-auto-playing-music-in-car/#:%7E:text=6.-,Disable%20Cellular%20Usage%20of%20Music%20App,-Music%20will%20start).

I also found this link: [Prevent Apple Music from Auto-Playing with CarPlay](https://kb.gizmocaresinc.com/en/prevent-apple-music-from-auto-playing-with-carplay) that says "there is no native way to disable Apple Music from playing when it connects to CarPlay", which leads me to think that it is not natively possible to stop Podcasts from playing automatically either. Either way, if you use the second solution I mentioned and disable the use of Cellular Data for Apple Music, it will most likely fix your problem.

Comment: My car's stereo does not seem to have an autoplay option to disable.  I will try to kill the cellular data, but wow, Apple really dropped the ball on this one.  Since I have unlimited data, I will lose the functionality of automatically downloading the Podcasts as I need them.  Not ideal, but I will try it and report back.

Comment: So I turned off cellular data on Podcasts and Music and it did not work.  The Podcast already saved on my phone continued playing.